# Issue rendering single quotes and double quotes on same line

Tags: jquery, html-escape-characters

I have a loop in which i'm attempting to add this line of code

Example

```
<div class="wb-share" data-wb-share='{"pnlId": "pnl1"}'></div>
```

My actual code is

```
var share = "<div class=\"wb-share\" data-wb-share='{\"pnlId\": \"pnl" + Id + "\"}'></div>";
```

Which renders as

```
<div class="wb-share" data-wb-share="{&quot;pnlId&quot;: &quot;pnl206259534&quot;}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` method and these escape the characters, check this snippet whit browser inspector.

```js
var share = "<div class=\"wb-share\" data-wb-share='{\"pnlId\": \"pnl1\"}'></div>";
document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = share
```

```css
.wb-share{ background: #000; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id='app'></div>
```